# Phabricator SVN Revision file context

Tags: phabricator

I cannot get phabricator to display the changes in using the file context. I got the "Context not available" on every file.

Does anyone know why is this not work? What should i do to debug this problem?

This seems a problem related with SVN only because its working with GIT.

Thanks.

Comment: This is addressed here:
https://secure.phabricator.com/T2465

Answer (score 0):

I bumped in the same problem recently and googled this question. I found out that the context is available only when diff is created via arcanist command line tool (`arc diff`) in Linux or Mac OS.

It won't work if you create a diff directly by pasting it in Phabricator/Differential or by using arcanist tool in Windows.

I tested this with arcanist on Ubuntu 14.04, Mac OS 10.10 (those two worked) and in Windows 7 (didn't work).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify whether you're using the `arc diff` command line tool, or manually uploading a diff via the Phab. web interface.

If you're not using `arc diff`, I have an answer for you: It's up to you to include the context yourself.  Phab. only knows what's in the diff/patch that you give it.  If you can't get the full context, that's a fault with your diff/patch, not with Phab.

If you're using a standard diff utility, like GNU diff, you can use the command-line arguments to dictate how much context to include in the output.  I usually use some obscenely large number, like 500 or 1000, to ensure that the entire file ends up in the output.

I just took a quick look at the svn command-line documentation, and it seems that there's no way to control how much context goes into the output. ...but maybe I'm wrong...

In any case, shortboy is correct that the easiest way to get the full file context is to use `arc diff`.